# Кастинг массива к IReadOnlyCollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net

Почему нижеследующий код работает?

```
int[] ixs = new int[10];
int cnt = ((IReadOnlyCollection<int>)ixs).Count;
```

Как это вообще компилируется? Ведь у массива нет свойства `Count` (у него есть `Length` и `LongLength`), соответственно - он не должен приводиться к `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Comment: кстати, интерфейсы на то и интерфейсы, что приведя к ним, можно пользоваться методами которые в этих интерфейсах описаны

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Свойства `Count` у массива и правда нету. Но для того, чтобы имплементировать интерфейс, оно и не нужно.

Есть такая штука в .NET — explicit interface implementation. Это когда класс имплементирует интерфейс, но не заводит метод с нужным именем. (Она и применяется в случае массива.)

Пример. Пусть у нас есть такой интерфейс:

```
interface I { void Run(); }
```

Тогда мы можем сделать так:

```
class C : I
{
    public void Run() { ... }
}
```

А можем и так:

```
class C : I
{
    void I.Run() { ... }
}
```

При этом интерфейс имплементирован в обоих случаях, но в первом случае у нас есть публичный метод `Run`, а во втором нету, и этот метод можно вызвать только через каст к нужному интерфейсу.

---

Для чего такая фича языка (explicit interface implementation) реально нужна? А вот для чего. Представьте себе, что вы хотите реализовать в классе *два* интерфейса, которые конфликтуют между собой, определяют функцию или свойство с одинаковым именем, которые нужно для разных интерфейсов реализовывать по-разному. Тогда вы можете написать две разные имплементации:

```
class C : IExecutioner, IAsyncModelObject
{
    Task IExecutioner.Execute() { /* казним приговорённого */ }
    Task IAsyncModelObject.Execute() { /* начинаем работу в фоне */ }
}
```

---

Любой массив в .NET произведён от `System.Array`. Самой имплементации конкретных массивов в исходниках фреймворка нету, она генерируется автоматически. [Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx#Anchor_6) говорит:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the Array class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and as a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array class.

В реальности, начиная с .NET 4.5, добавлены тем же механизмом ещё два интерфейса: `System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<T>` and `System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. Все эти интерфейсы реализует не класс `Array`, а производные от него классы, представляющие собой массивы конкретного типа.

Посмотрим интерфейсы, реализуемые типом `System.Array` и конкретным типом массива `int[]`. Такой код:

```
foreach (var i in typeof(System.Array).GetInterfaces())
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

выдаёт

```
System.ICloneable
System.Collections.IList
System.Collections.ICollection
System.Collections.IEnumerable
System.Collections.IStructuralComparable
System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable
```

В то же время

```
foreach (var i in typeof(int[]).GetInterfaces())
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

выдаёт

```
System.ICloneable
System.Collections.IList
System.Collections.ICollection
System.Collections.IEnumerable
System.Collections.IStructuralComparable
System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Int32]
```

Итак, лишь конкретные массивы имплементируют `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, сам `System.Array` этого не делает.

---

Окей, но откуда же берётся сам код свойства? Заглянем в [исходники .NET](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,680) (`Array` -- базовый класс всех массивов) видим:

```
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
{
    // ... 
    int ICollection.Count
    { get { return Length; } }
```

Таким образом, свойства `Count` действительно нет, есть лишь свойство `ICollection.Count`, которое доступно только через каст к интерфейсу. Это показывает, откуда взялась реализация `ICollection`, но что же насчёт `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`?  Как правильно отмечает @andreycha в соседнем ответе, для реализации generic-интерфейсов используется немного компиляторной магии и класс `SZArrayHelper`.

Из [исходников](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,2715):

```
// This class is needed to allow an SZ array of type T[] to expose IList<T>,
// IList<T.BaseType>, etc., etc. all the way up to IList<Object>. When the following call is
// made:
//
//   ((IList<T>) (new U[n])).SomeIListMethod()
//
// the interface stub dispatcher treats this as a special case, loads up SZArrayHelper,
// finds the corresponding generic method (matched simply by method name), instantiates
// it for type <T> and executes it.
```

Перевод:

```
// Этот класс (SZArrayHelper) нужен, чтобы позволить массиву T[] имплементировать
// IList<T>, IList<T.BaseType> и т. д. аж до IList<Object>. если вызывается
//
//   ((IList<T>) (new U[n])).МетодИзIList()
//
// код, отвечающий за нахождение интерфейсов в классе считает это особым случаем,
// загружает SZArrayHelper, находит соответствующий обобщённый метод (просто по имени)
// инстанциирует его для нужного типа T и выполняет.
```

Это значит, что каст работает, но код реально находится в `SZArrayHelper`, и то, что этот код используется, гарантируется специальными трюками рантайма. Реальное место нахождения свойства Count — [`SZArrayHelper.get_Count`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,2770).

Comment: а как он все-таки из ICollection в IReadOnlyCollection?

Comment: @Grundy: Никак, эти интерфейсы добавляются при помощи «магии». Написал обновление.

Comment: Ага, в соседнем ответе как раз про это :-)

Comment: Мне кажется вам нужно поменять части ответа местами. То, что у вас идет после линии -- первично для ответа на вопрос. А про неявную реализацию -- уже так, дополнительная информация, которая тут в общем не при чем.

Comment: @andreycha: Угу, линии отображают скорее порядок _написания_ :)

Comment: @andreycha: Перетасовал части, сейчас должно выглядеть логичнее.

Comment: Вот за это я и не люблю языки с высоким уровнем абстракции — некоторые вещи сделаны просто через Ж и совершенно не очевидны

Comment: @ixSci: Это вы о чём? Об explicit interface implementation, или о том, что `Array` не имплементирует `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, а только порождённые классы типа `int[]`?

Comment: Второе и плюс то, как это реализовано — too much magic

Comment: @ixSci: Ну, они не могли сделать правильно, через generic, в первой версии, т. к. там generic'ов ещё не было. Сейчас можно было бы, но это порушило бы обратную совместимость. Такая магия есть, думаю, во всех языках, кроме ассемблера. Даже в низкоуровневом C есть compiler intrinsics.

Answer (score 3):

> он не должен приводиться к IReadOnlyCollection

Заглянем в [исходники](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,156e066ecc4ccedf):

> Note that we make a T[] (single-dimensional w/ zero as the lower
>   bound) implement both IList<U> and IReadOnlyList<U>, where T : U
>   dynamically. See the SZArrayHelper class for details.

Что говорит о том, что массив неявным образом имплементирует `IList<>` и `IReadOnlyList<>` (очевидно, какая-то внутренняя магия, коей в дотнете хватает). `IReadOnlyList<>` в свою очередь имплементирует `IReadOnlyCollection<>`. Поэтому в вашем коде приведение срабатывает корректно. А про неявную имплементацию вам уже ответил VladD.

Comment: не знаю стоит ли добавить, что так как имплементирует `IReadOnlyList` которая наследуется от `IReadOnlyCollection` то и соответственно `IReadOnlyCollection` тоже имплементирует. Просто сейчас в цитате `IReadOnlyList`, а дальше в ответе и вообще в вопросе про `IReadOnlyCollection`

Comment: @Grundy да, спасибо, добавил пояснение.